# How to affect Gatsby/React useState of single element within list

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

How do I affect the state of one element within a list? Currently, onClick is applying the "selected" class to all list elements.

**JSX**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default () => {
    const [showPhoto, setShowPhoto] = useState(false)

    return (
        <ul>
            {photos.map(photo => (
                <li className={showPhoto ? 'selected' : ''} onClick={() => setShowPhoto(!showPhoto)}>
                    <img />
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

**SASS**

```
li
    ...
    img
        ...
    &.selected
        ...
        img
            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue I needed to apply a 'key' conditional to the `className` and assign the 'key' value the to `showPhoto` variable via the `onClick` listener as follows...

```
<ul>
    {photos.map(photo => (
        <li
            className={showPhoto === photo.id ? style.show : ''}
            onClick={() => setShowPhoto(showPhoto === false ? photo.id : false)}
        >
            <img />
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

what i would do create separate reactNode for your list item and place on click there. cause now you are just adding class on every item in array.

```
const ParentNode=()=>(
  <ul/>
    {arrayOfSomething.map((something,idx)=>
      <key={something+idx}childNode/>
    )}
  </ul>)
```

//then

```
const ChildNode =()=>{
  const[isShow, setIsShow]=useState(false)
  return(
    <li onClick={()=>setIsShow(!isShow)}>
      {isShow?something : something else}
    </li>
  )
}
```